# Running python script from C#

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, process

I am tring to run python script from C#

and from the shell is being opened but, the script don't run

I know it since it should create a file

How can I run the process?

```
Process p = new Process(); // create process (i.e., the python program
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // make sure we can read the output from stdout
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"T:\barakr\360_3G_daily_report\2016.03.15\0615319253\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; //PanelsDirectory[j] + "\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; // start the python program with two parameters                        
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a backslash in your string you need to escape it like this : "\"

So your code will be :

```
Process p = new Process(); // create process (i.e., the python program
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // make sure we can read the output from stdout
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"T:\\barakr\\360_3G_daily_report\\2016.03.15\\0615319253\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; //PanelsDirectory[j] + "\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; // start the python program with two parameters                        
p.Start();
```

Have a nice day and hope i helped you ;)

edit: Apparently the double backslash is not needed when there is an @ before the string. Try to test your location directly with your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put two '\' in each '\' in this line:

```
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"T:\barakr\360_3G_daily_report\2016.03.15\0615319253\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; //PanelsDirectory[j] + "\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; // start the python program with two parameters
```

Check this webpage: https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/950783-two-ways-run-python-programs-c

Edit:

Try like this:

```
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"T:\\barakr\\360_3G_daily_report\\2016.03.15\\0615319253\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; //PanelsDirectory[j] + "\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py"; // start the python program with two parameters
```

I hope this will helpful to you :)

Comment: It seems that is not neccesary to put a double '/' if you use '@' before string, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a double backslash that should be a single one at the end of this line :

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"T:\barakr\360_3G_daily_report\2016.03.15\0615319253\\powerlink_logs_mrg.py";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right to me.  The double slash should not be necessary since the string constant is preceded with @.  What I recommend you try is copy and paste the exe path and the argument path into a shell window, then run the exe from the shell window to be sure that you don't have a typo in those paths.

Comment: it should be 1 slesh. change it. same result.